# Flutter : How to just enable 7 days from now when using date_picker_timeline

Tags: flutter, datepicker, pub.dev

I am using [date_picker_timeline](https://pub.dev/packages/date_picker_timeline) library on pub.dev

But I don't know how to make it just to enable the next 7 days from now.
Please help me to solve this problem.

[image]

[Example](https://pub.dev/packages/date_picker_timeline/example)

I tried to add some code in this block but it's still not working

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can give daysCount to the DatePicker like bellow:

```
DatePicker(
    DateTime.now(),
    initialSelectedDate: DateTime.now(),
    selectionColor: Colors.black,
    selectedTextColor: Colors.white,
    daysCount: 7,
    onDateChange: (date) {
      // New date selected
      setState(() {
        _selectedValue = date;
      });
    },
  ),
```